# Losing SSH sessions when applying iptables rules

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I have an issue I cannot explain with SSH and iptables alone. To put it short: if I'm connected on a remote host (running Ubuntu 18.04) with SSH and I execute a script to apply iptables rules, I lose my running SSH session. I can connect again, but my running session is lost.

The script flushes iptables rules with the command `netfilter-persistent flush` and then applies this ruleset in `iptables-save` format:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/XX -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT DROP: "
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD DROP: "
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x/XX -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT DROP: "
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

After the script completes my session is lost and I can see blocked SSH packets in both directions in `/var/log/kern.log`. This would make sense if the connection tracking information were lost, but I can still the connection with `conntrack -L` (the server is a VM, so I can check even when my SSH connection is lost).

More strangely, if I do `netfilter-persistent flush && ./myscript`, my connection is kept; but if I run the two commands one after the other, I lose the connection. Also, if I run the two commands on the VM TTY, I don't lose my connection.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Are the iptables rules executed on the remote host or on the local host?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it was not clear in the post, but the rules are applyied on the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

Your default policy is set to "DROP".

So in the time between flushing and adding the rules, no paket is accepted and you loose your connection...

If your script fails to add the rules, you are screwed.

You should set the policy to accept and add a rule at the end (of each chain) to drop everything that was not matched...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `netfilter-persistent flush` flush rules, but also reset default policies to “ACCEPT” (it's not clear from the command, but that's what it does), so unfortunately I don't think the problem come from there.